# CATransform3D visual artifacts after UIView animation

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, catransform3d

I have a simple scrollview inside of the root view.  The scrollview size occupies the entire width/height of the screen.

After I performed a 3d rotation on the scrollview's x-axis, which worked nicely.  There is some weird artifacts at the bottom of the screen.  Like pieces of the scrollview cloned on the root view.

Attached a screen here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWN44.jpg

Notice the blue/purple streaks near the bottom of the screen.

Is there a way to get rid of that?  They appear while animating so a simple screen refresh  after the animation wouldn't work.

**UPDATED with code:**

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = 1.0f / -500.0f;
CATransform3D translation = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0, -20.0, 0.0);
CATransform3D finalTransform = CATransform3DRotate(translation, 45.0f, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        [viewImageScroll setClearsContextBeforeDrawing:YES];
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f delay:0.
    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut)
    animations:^{
    [viewImageScroll.layer setTransform:finalTransform];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [viewImageScroll setClearsContextBeforeDrawing:YES];
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = 1.0f / -500.0f;
    CATransform3D flyAway = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0., -7000., -10000.0);
    flyAway = CATransform3DRotate(flyAway, 45.0f, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f delay:0.
    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedCurve)
    animations:^{
        NSLog(@"done");
        [viewImageScroll.layer setTransform:flyAway];
        [viewImageScroll setAlpha:0];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"done and done");
        [(X1NavigationController *)self.navigationController popControllerWithTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown];
    }];

}];
```

Comment: This happens on both simulator and on the device.

Comment: 1 - Could you show the source code. It may help. 2 - Do you have the issue only with this background ?

Comment: Vincent Zgueb: I've added code sample.  Tested also with a simple solid black color and it's the same artifacts.

Comment: Vincent Zgueb: I've removed the child UIImageView inside of the UIScrollView and just set a background color to the UIScrollView and the artifact is gone.  However, I do think I will need a UIImageView later on anyway so the problem will appear again.  Is this some kind of clipping issue that can be handled?